# Toolbar behind status bar with API 21

Tags: android, android-layout

I've a fragment with a CoordinatorLayout

When i run the app with **API 19** the behavior is right : 
The toolbar is below the status bar and the FAB button of the main_activity go away :

[image: Api19]

But with the **API 21 and +** :
The toolbar is behind the status bar and the FAB button of the main_activity don't go away :
[image: Api21]

Layout file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/caves_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/caves_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/caves_collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="78dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="124dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/caves_backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:background="@drawable/drawer_header_bg"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/caves_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/caves_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/caves_fab"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/caves_appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_discuss"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I've add a specify style-v21 xml file

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.Design">
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementsUseOverlay">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I'dont find and understand the problem.

Comment: The behavior is correct for the activities but not for the fragments with API 21.

Answer (score 22):

add `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"`to the `CoordinatorLayout`

Comment: this fixed the bug very well!

Comment: You are awesome! Saved me many more hours of frustration. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

Had a similar problem (exemplified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35318930/why-do-i-get-an-extra-50-pixels-of-vscrolling-on-my-appbarlayout-with-scrollent))

How I made it work was to add `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` to the `AppBarLayout` and have it on `true` on the `CoordinatorLayout`

Comment: Works for me, I had 

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    ..
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        ..
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

Answer (score 2):

take off this line:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

Comment: Thanks but dont works.  This behavior is just when i use fragment and with API 21 and +