# Why do I get an extra 50 pixels of vscrolling on my AppBarLayout with scroll|enterAlways?

Tags: android, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport

I have the following layout (almost the same as the scrollingActivity generated by *Android Studio* )

Notice the `layout_height`s and `layout_scrollFlags`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.man.myapplication.ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

### Problem

After starting the application, the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` doesn't start from below the statusbar, but from behind it and it still can be scrolled down 50 pixels. 
(Notice in the gif below in the first view as I start the app)

[image]

+ sometimes it snaps below the header (where it should be) when playing with scroll.

Note: this does not appear with the `exitUntilCollapsed` flag

### Question

Is there any way to get rid of that 50 extra pixels scroll and make the `Toolbar` appear properly under the statusbar?

(currently am debugging the design-support library)

Answer (score 2):

Ok I've found a way to get rid of the extra scroll (though not an explanation for **why** it is happening):

### Quickfix

Changing the `android:fitsSystemWindows` on the `AppBarLayout` to `false` gets rid of the extra scroll.

### What happens

This setting makes the `AppBarLayout` begin its layout from the very top of the screen instead from below the statusbar, which somehow gets rid of the *weirdscroll*.

### Note

Though this way your `Toolbar` won't be hidden nicely below the statusbar.

### Result

[image]

### Footnotes

What is still a mistery, is why doesn't the above behavior take into consideration the statusbar and adds that extra scrollheight. in its original form.

Comment: Awesome. I've been trying to figure out what was happening and this fixed it. Main layout keeps it set to true.