# CollapsingToolbar odd behavior in API 21

Tags: android, android-studio, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

For some reason, I am getting this odd state where the status bar seems to have moved below the collapsingtoolbarlayout, and the status bar is blank. I see this issue when I swipe the CollapsingToolbarLayout up and down repeatedly. The image below shows a blue horizontal line beneath the collapsingToolbarLayout, and I think this is actually the status bar? (I don't know for sure). I've tried using setFitSystemWindow(true) in multiple places but can't seem to fix this.

The issue seems to happen when I use the `SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS` flag. It doesn't occur when I swap this out with `SCROLL_FLAG_SNAP`. This doesn't occur in API 19.

I am using a programmatically generated collapsingToolbarLayout.

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = new CollapsingToolbarLayout(this);
    AppBarLayout.LayoutParams collapsingToolbarlayoutParams = new AppBarLayout.LayoutParams(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    collapsingToolbarlayoutParams.setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS |
    AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_EXIT_UNTIL_COLLAPSED);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setContentScrimColor(ThemeUtil.resolveThemeColor(this, android.R.attr.colorPrimary));   
    } else {
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setContentScrimColor(resources.getColor(R.color.primary_col));
    }
    appBarLayout.setFitsSystemWindows(true);
    appBarLayout.addView(collapsingToolbarLayout, collapsingToolbarLayoutParams);
    CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams primaryToolbarLayoutParams = new CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams(CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, actionBarSize);
    primaryToolbarLayoutParams.setCollapseMode(CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams.COLLAPSE_MODE_PIN);
    primaryToolbarParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    collapsingToolbarLayout.addView(primaryToolbar, primaryToolbarLayoutParams);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sell_augmented_list_item_background, collapsingToolbarLayout, false);
    ImageView backgroundImage  = (ImageView)imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.m_Image);             backgroundImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_stock);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.addView(backgroundImage, 0);

    View mLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.m_layout, collapsingToolbarLayout, false);
    exampleText.setText("Some Text");
    collapsingToolbarLayout.addView(mLayout, 1);
}
```

[image: odd state]

*UPDATE* This answer solved my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37105296/4138919

Comment: This answer solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37105296/4138919

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toolbar behind status bar with API 21](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33334185/toolbar-behind-status-bar-with-api-21)