# CollapsingToolbarLayout shows bar under image in API 26

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

After upgrading the support library from *v25.4.0* to *v26.0.0*, the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is not fitting to the content inside but showing an empty space below (which could be the size of the status bar). To illustrate:

**With v25.4.0:**

[image: With v25.4.0]

**With v26.0.0:**

[image: With v26.0.0]

The `XML` layout of that `Activity` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:src="@drawable/material_flat"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="86dp"
                android:layout_height="86dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Minions ipsum ..." />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I've tried playing with the `android:fitsSystemWindows` value, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33334185/toolbar-behind-status-bar-with-api-21/37105296#37105296), but the result is not the expected.
If you want to check further details, the code of my implementation is [this Github repo](https://github.com/siempredelao/testproject).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I have the same problem since 26.0.0 and looks like it's still an issue on 27.1.0

Comment: @FlashAsh99 take a look at my answer below? I have give out some useful solution which worth a try.

Answer (score 5):

I try to edit your code and I got the idea result you are trying to achieve:

[image]

The only thing I edit is, instead of setting the layout_height of AppBarLayout to `wrap_content`, I change it to `190dp`.

[image]

I came out with this solution from this CheeseSquare repo: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare , this is how it make the idea effect for `ImageView under transparent statusBar`:

[image]

As you can see, it's fine to set a fix height for `AppBarLayout`.

**Why in your post, the blue bar show up?**

The answer to this question come from two factor:
1. You set the height of AppBarLayout to be `wrap_content`;
2. Your `imageView` fitsSystemWindows to be true.

When you set fitsSystemWindows to be true, the imageView will consume the window inset, and the view itself goes up exactly the same height as the statusBar. And when that happened, the AppBarLayout doesn't adjust it's height according to this imageView sliding, so an ugly bottom bar shows up.

**How to fix this issue?**

One way to fix is try to set a fix height for the AppBarLayout in you xml file. This is the easy way to do just like I show above.

What if you don't know the exactly height of your picture, like you are downloading this picture from the internet? My suggestion is, you can also handle this inside your activity. When the download of the picture background is finished, you can get the measure height of your image, then just the the height for your AppBarLayout programmatically. This should also resolve the problem and leave no bar anymore.

Comment: removing fitsSystemWindows is what fixed it for me,